# Как настроить gerrit + unit tests + CI (unity3d проект)

Tags: git, unity3d, юнит-тесты, непрерывная-интеграция

Какой существует лучший вариант развертки окружения, основанного на gerrit? Необходимо перед отправкой коммита на проверку в gerrit делать юнит-тесты и собирать билд на iOS и Android. В случае провала билдов или юнит тестов не давать отправить этот коммит на проверку.

Answer (score 1):

Не могу сказать наверняка, но могу попробовать направить вас в нужном направлении: не желаете ли воспользоваться [хуками Git'а](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-Git), настроенными на commit? 
Т.е. например, в корне вашего репозитория git найдите директорию hooks (`.git/hooks`), затем создайте там файл с соответствующим именем (имя файла должно соответствовать имени перехватчика), т.е. например, вам подойдет `pre-commit`, внутри которого выполнить необходимые действия.

---

Если вас, все-таки, заинтересует данный подход, то можете более подробно ознакомиться [здесь](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-Git) и [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/114273/).